# Android AdvancedRecyclerView SwitchButton Blocked Click going to Parent Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

this is going to be a tricky question but not for you guys but for me.

Explaining what I want will be quite hard, so bear with me.

**I'm using the AdvancedRecyclerView Library specifically the Draggable and Swipping one**

Here is the Layout I'm using for each item in my List:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
       Copyright (C) 2015 Haruki Hasegawa

       Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
       you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
       You may obtain a copy of the License at

           http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

       Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
       distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
       WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
       See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
       limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- NOTE: should use FrameLayout or RelativeLayout for parent of the "@id/container" view (for Android 2.3 compatibility) -->
<FrameLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/commonListItemStyle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_swipe_item_neutral">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/statusBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|left"
                android:background="#20000000"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:divider="@drawable/list_divider_v"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/drag_handle"
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
                    android:background="@color/material_grey300"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="244dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:divider="@drawable/list_divider_v"
                    android:dividerPadding="4dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:showDividers="middle"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/deviceName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                        android:text="deviceName" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/deviceDescription"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                        android:text="deviceDescription" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <com.kyleduo.switchbutton.SwitchButton
                    android:id="@+id/turnOn"
                    style="@style/SwitchButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    app:kswBackMeasureRatio="2.2"
                    app:kswBackRadius="2dp"
                    app:kswTextOff="Off"
                    app:kswTextOn="On"
                    app:kswThumbRadius="2dp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

The most important things in this Layout file is the **FrameLayout** with id **container** and the **SwitchButton** at the end with id **turnOn**.

There is an **ClickListener** on the **container** and in the **SwitchButton**. The first one trigger another Fragment and the second one just trigger the Switch.

The thing is that if the SwitchButton is Disabled for clicking or Swipping the click action goes to the **container** and that is not what I want. I tried everything at the code but I think my problem is within the layout file...

For Example: If the **SwitchButton** is blocked to click or swipe the User shouldn't be able to do anything with that Button but instead what is happening is that when the User click in the blocked button the click goes to the **container** and something that is not desired will execute.

**Note**: The user itself can choose click on the **container** even if the **SwitchButton** is blocked but I do not wish that the **container** gets triggered when clicked in the blocked button.

I tried my best to explain my problem, if you guys request more info about the code I'll provide here.

Thanks as always,
Igor Morse.

Comment: `If the SwitchButton is blocked to click or swipe` how exactly do you implement that part?

Comment: I just disabled it using **SwitchButton.setEnabled(false)** and to ensure I made **setClikable** to **true**.

Comment: If a view is in a disabled state (i.e. `spinner.setEnabled(false)` or `android:enabled="false"`), than it won't allow the touch event to go higher up. If you still experience that issue, than please post a simple project on github with just that behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The problem

Your problem comes from the implementation of the `SwitchButton` library.

When you have a `View.OnClickListener` attached to your `SwitchButton` and the switch is enabled, everything works as expected because taps go to that click listener. However, when the switch is disabled, the taps go to `SwitchButton`'s implementation of `onTouchEvent()`. Here's the first piece of that method (from the [`SwitchButton` source](https://github.com/kyleduo/SwitchButton/blob/master/SwitchButton/library/src/main/java/com/kyleduo/switchbutton/SwitchButton.java#L530) code):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (!isEnabled() || !isClickable() || !isFocusable()) {
        return false;
    }
```

If you check the documentation for `onTouchEvent()`, you'll find:

> **Returns**:
>   True if the event was handled, false otherwise.

So the SwitchButton library is explicitly saying that it *does not* handle taps, and these taps should bubble up the view hierarchy.

### The solution(s)

I see two relatively easy solutions.

The first is to create your own custom subclass of `SwitchButton` and change `onTouchEvent()` to consume clicks even when disabled:

```
public class MySwitchButton extends SwitchButton {

    public MySwitchButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return !isEnabled() || super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

The second is to wrap your `SwitchButton` in another view and assign a `View.OnClickListener` to this wrapper to intercept the click events:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/interceptor"
    ...>

    <com.kyleduo.switchbutton.SwitchButton
        .../>

</FrameLayout>
```

And in Java:

```
findViewById(R.id.interceptor).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do nothing
    }
});
```

Personally, I prefer the first.

Comment: Thats very interesting ! I did looked at the Source Code but did not paid attention to that.

Yeah the first solution its way better, thanks for pointing that out and thanks for the complete answer of this matter.